# How to import ember-dynamic-component into a test

Tags: ember-cli

I'm using [ember-dynamic-component](https://github.com/minutebase/ember-dynamic-component) and in my component test, I'm getting the following error:

> Handlebars error: Could not find property 'dynamic-component' on object

I've tried

```
needs: ['view:dynamic-component']
needs: ['component:dynamic-component']
needs: ['helper:dynamic-component']
```

but they're not working. Any ideas on how to make my tests aware of dynamic-component?